# Transfer values from 2D array into 3D array to track changes

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I'm a novice coder so this will hopefully be a very simple problem to solve.

I'm trying to copy from a 2D array into a 3D array to track changes at set intervals.

```
    For i = 2 To nx + 1
        For j = 2 To ny + 1                               

            If k = (interval * z) Then Worksheets("Extent").Cells(i, j, z) = Worksheets("Water").Cells(i, j) And z = (z + 1)

        Next j
    Next i
```

What I'm hoping this does is duplicate the 2D array into a new 'layer' in the 3D array for each iteration of 'k' that matches the interval.

At the moment I get an error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment (Error 450)"

What is broken here?

Thanks in advance!
Phil

Comment: `Cells(i, j, z)` is wrong

Comment: Please use the `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(nx,ny).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(nx,ny).Value` type of array copying for fast results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A worksheet has only two dimension, so **Cells()** can only have two arguments.

**EDIT#1**

You can get around this by using more than one worksheet

Say in **VBA** we have an array *Ary(10,10,2),*  this could be in two worksheets, each sheet containing a 10x10.

Comment: So is there no way to store the separate values in the same cell on a worksheet? So cell (i, j) would have values 1, 2, 3 (or whatever the values are) and so on. Would I need a worksheet for each interval?